# Modify maps by reference in template class

Tags: c++, templates, reference

**Hey guys!**

I have school project to make. In the project I have to create a map_storage template class that's able to store/ know what maps it's going to modify and do different operations on them.

The main.cpp file was already created for me, so that I can check if my code was correct.

**Template class**:

```
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#ifndef MAPALIGN_H
#define MAPALIGN_H

template<class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> >
class map_storage{
public:

    void add(std::map<Key, T, Compare> &temp_map){
        data_.push_back(temp_map);
    }

    void doSomething(){
        std::cout << data_.size() << std::endl;
        //This does something to all maps in the vector.
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::map<Key, T, Compare> > data_;

};

#endif
```

When I modify the maps in data_ (add new key,values etc.) I want to see the changes in main too and the same thing for the other way around.

My question is that How can I store the references of the maps in a template class?

**Example of the main method:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mapalign.h"
#include <string>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> map1;
  
  map_storage<std::string int> ms;
  
  ms.add(map1);
  
  map1["asd"] = 1;
  map1["dsa"] = 2;
  

  ms.doSomething();
  //Tests that are checking that operations on map1 were finished on the map with size of 2 and not the empty one.

  .....

  return 0;
}
```

So in the main.cpp file its mandatory that all modifications are shown on the maps reference that was added to the template class.

In this case the doSomething() function does something with the map that has "asd" 1, "dsa" 2 key-value pairs, and not just the empty copy of the map that was added earlier to the vector.

During the doSomething() operation we have to know all map data to accordingly modify data in the other maps.

If anyone has any idea to this problem I would really appreciate it.

(I know that c++ does not support storing references in an array nor vector, so there must be another way that I can't figure out)

Thank you again.

Comment: Having objects depend on other objects whose lifetime they do not control will always create major problems and difficult to understand bugs.

Comment: How did the guy with the correct answer disappear?

Comment: They chose to delete their answer, for whatever reason.

Comment: @SuperBlaze I have added method 2 in my answer which basically is the same as that answer i think except that i have some minor comment indicating the changes that i made in my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot have vector of lvalue references. You could instead store pointers inside the vector as shown below:

```
template<class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> >
class map_storage{
public:
//------------------------------------v--------------->pointer
    void add(std::map<Key, T, Compare>* temp_map){
        data_.push_back(temp_map);
    }

    void doSomething(){

        std::cout << data_.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout<< data_.at(0)->size(); //prints 2
        
    }

private:
//---------------------------------------v------------->pointer
    std::vector<std::map<Key, T, Compare>* > data_;

};

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> map1;

  map_storage<std::string, int> ms;
//-----------------------^----------->added comma here which was missing in the original code
  
  ms.add(&map1);
  
  map1["asd"] = 1;
  map1["dsa"] = 2;
  
  
  ms.doSomething();
  
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/O-m00apeZ)

Also, make sure that the you don't dereference pointers that are pointing to objects that no longer exist.

##### Method 2

```
template<class Key, class T, class Compare = std::less<Key> >
class map_storage{
public:
//------------------------------------v--------------->reference
    void add(std::map<Key, T, Compare>& temp_map){
        data_.push_back(&temp_map);
    }

    void doSomething(){

        std::cout << data_.size() << std::endl;
        std::cout<< data_.at(0)->size(); //prints 2
        
    }

private:
//---------------------------------------v------------->pointer
    std::vector<std::map<Key, T, Compare>* > data_;

};

int main()
{
  std::map<std::string, int> map1;

  map_storage<std::string, int> ms;
//-----------------------^----------->added comma here which was missing in the original code
  
  ms.add(map1);
  
  map1["asd"] = 1;
  map1["dsa"] = 2;
  
  
  ms.doSomething();
  
}
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/PltwzykaF)

Comment: Your answer would be correct but I can't modify the main.cpp file so the ms.add() function HAS to pass a map1 and not &map1.

Comment: @SuperBlaze I have added method 2 in my answer, check it out. In method 2 you don't have to change anything in main.cpp as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's just what I was looking for.